# Nav bar with position fixed covering H2 when linked within page

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar at the top of a page with position fixed.  The links in the bar go to H2 tags below on the same page. However when the link is selected the link bar covers the H2 title it is linking to. I know it's because the Nav is not in the flow of those other elements.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Post your code here, we're not psychic.

Comment: any code??? that would make it possible to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use anchors instead of IDs on your headings, then pull the anchors up above the headings:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/uZ7n7

```
<a name="link2"></a>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>

.content a {
    margin-top: -80px;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing any code my only suggestion would be set `z-index` on element that is getting covered.